# The Taylor series of $f(x) = (e^x-1)(\tan {x})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to write out the Taylor series of 
$f(x) = (e^x-1)(\tan {x})$ centered around a = 0.

Am I missing something here, because the derivatives seem to get messy by the second derivative:

$f'(x) = (e^x-1)(\sec^2 {x})+ (e^x)(\tan x)$

$f''(x) = (e^x)(\sec^2 {x})+ 2(e^x-1)\sec^2 {x} \tan{x}+ (e^x)(\tan x) + (e^x)(\tan x)$

I still need a couple more terms which will get even messier. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you need it to a *specific* order?

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x=1+x+\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2!}+\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3!}+・・・ $$

now $$ \tan x=x+\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3}+\displaystyle\frac{2x^5}{15}+\displaystyle\frac{17x^7}{315}+・・・ $$

Therefore, we can conclude that $$(e^x-1)\tan x=(x+\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2!}+\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3!}+・・・)(x+\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3}+\displaystyle\frac{2x^5}{15}+\displaystyle\frac{17x^7}{315}+・・・)$$

Which I assume should make things a bit easier.